# ¿Cómo comprobar ambos datos en minúsculas?

Tags: php

En mi sistema tienen la posibilidad de registrar sus datos de acceso en minúsculas o mayúscula o variados y los registros no tienen problema si no en el filtro de comprobación de usuarios e email.

Veamos cómo se da el problema:

Si enviamos un correo a las siguientes direcciones de correo:

```
Email: -> Admin@admin.com       o usuario: ->    Jose
Email: -> AdMin@admin.com       o usuario: ->    JoSe
Email: -> Admin@AdMin.com
Email: ->ADMIN@ADMIN.COM   o usuario: ->    JOSE
```

Toda la información llegará al mismo correo porque para los servidores de correo esa información sigue siendo lo mismo sin importar el orden de minúscula y mayúsculas.

Ahora en mi sistema. Sí el usuario utiliza ese mismo mecanismos en mi sistema de registro el sistema los deja registrar.

Cómo le pasó un filtro mediante PHP, que compruebe ambos datos en minúsculas sin importar como estén los datos registrados ni como el usuario los haya enviado, lo importante es que ambos datos se compruebe en minúsculas.

Mis actuales comprobaciones:

```
if($email == $emailDB){
     echo "email utilizado";
}
if($username == $usernameDB) {
   echo "usuario no disponemos";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En **php** existe el **strtolower**, el cual te permitirá convertir tu cadena a minúsculas que es lo estas pidiendo:

```
if(strtolower($email) == strtolower($emailDB)){
     echo "email utilizado";
}
if(strtolower($username) == strtolower($usernameDB)) {
   echo "usuario no disponemos";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Si lo que quieres es que ambos `emails` y ambos `username` sean comparados ambos en minuscula, podrias usar la funcion `strtolower()` que trae php:

```
if(strtolower($email) == strtolower($emailDB)){
     echo "email utilizado";
}
if(strtolower($username) == strtolower($usernameDB)) {
   echo "usuario no disponemos";
}
```

Comment: en que si diferencia tu respuesta a la de @David?

Comment: Es una respuesta que vengo a ver ahora. Disculpadme. Y bueno para responder a tu pregunta: realmente no, no se diferencia en nada.